# What would cause an array assign in a closure to transform the array into an array of functions?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**Edit**

For anyone thinking I'm passing `JSON.parse()` an array/object...I'm passing it a string. I put a comment with the console output of it to the answer thinking this is what I did. Also check the screen show to compare `obj.data` to `newData`...if I assign one...the opposite gets corrupted.

**Original**

So I have this excerpt of code. The `nx.Equip.op()` call which the then is coming off of is what follows the internal `$ajax` operation.

My problem is that when I assign the `data` member which is an array...to anything...and set it via `this.setState({storagePayments: obj.data})` or `this.state.storagePayments = obj.data`...either way...when I log to console...it shows it's an array of functions...rather than the original fields. If I log `JSON.parse(data).data` directly to console...that will show the proper array. I've tried all sorts of things...such as copying it to a new array...like in the except. Whichever one I assign...it is the array of functions...and the opposite is the correct array of fields.

Seems like that is a contradiction...and not something I'm doing wrong...but I obviously could be missing something. Below I have a snip of the console when I log `obj.data` and `newData` which was a array I explicitly pushed new elements to in the code snippet. And `newData` shows as the array of functions and obj.data has the correct array I need.

If I do nothing but set `storagePayments` to `obj.data` instead of `newData`...then `obj.data` becomes the array of functions...and they switch roles. At first I thought it might be React...so I assigned to `this.state.storagePayments` and the same thing happened. Not to mention the weirdness is in the original variable logged before the assignment anyway...but it always matches the one ultimately assigned.

[image]

```
nextPromise = nextPromise.then(() => {
  return nx.Equip.op({
    endpoint: '/data',
    method: 'GET',
    data: {
      data_type: Payment.data_type,
      response_type: 'all',
      filter_by: `HEX(payment_guid) IN (${storageGuids})`,
      start_index: 0,
      number_of_records: 1000000
    }
  }).then(data => {
    var obj = JSON.parse(data);
    var newData = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < obj.data.length; i++)
      newData.push(obj.data[i]);
    this.setState({storagePayments: newData});
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are passing JSON.parse() an array when it operates on strings and converts them to objects/arrays. You will have to iterate over the array and pass the index data to JSON.parse().

[JSON.parse() MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

Comment: No...I'm passing it a string...which I returned from my backend...it's not pre-parsed. Below is from the console...I logged it in case I actually missed something...but this is how I send and parse all the data in the app. This is just acting strange.

"data { "data": [{"data_type":"tblPayment","prefix":"payment","payment_guid":"653380567a954e0db19b2408fe737111","payment_datecreated":1561169368,"paymenttype_guid":"d3b6d7123cab4d8ca4dc7e38bbf3e2ed","payment_amount":0,"mailmethod_guid":"bbf6af60dc474a72ad9af3c9e7619281"}],
"count": 1,
"total": 1
}
typeof(data) string"